# Yii create BaseController for Layout

Tags: layout, yii, controller

I was reading this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/28/#hh1) for "**How to implement multiple page layouts in an application**" is easy until it says: to use a controller for all layout , you have better create **BaseController** in protected/components/BaseController.php ,it is easy , i created php file with this content:

```
abstract class BaseController extends CController
{
    public $crumbs=array();
    public $portlets=array();
    public $portlets2=array();
}
```

and i put these lines to main.ph in components section:

```
    'BaseController'=>array(
            'class'=>'application.components.BaseControllert',
        ),
```

and when i use in my layout:

> $this->portlets

it return

> Property "HomeController.portlets" is not defined.

which means it look inside main controller for that variable.

How could i solve this problem ?

- all layout code written according to this link [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/28/#hh1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot that all your controllers must extends this class.

Read carefully : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/28/#hh1

> then we can derive from this base class each individual concrete
>   controller class

You just have to modify your controllers like this :

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
.....
}
```